# Automatically placing TikZ in a float/figure

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there a way to insert a diagram generated by [Tikz/PGF](http://www.texample.net/tikz/) directly from within a LaTex file? Currently, I am writing it in its own file, compiling it with `pdflatex` and then including the generated output file as an image.

Comment: Oops, this appears to be a duplicate question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28258/what-is-the-correct-way-to-caption-a-tikzpicture

Comment: If you are producing the pictures in a separate file (recommended), then you should also consider using the `standalone` package. An example is in this question on [crop entire document around figure](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32583/crop-entire-document-around-figure/32584#32584)

Comment: @PeterGrill the `standalone` package appears to be a more complex version of the `input` command does it not?

Comment: The `standalone` package can be used to produce complete compilable documents with the `tikzpicture`s, and then you can use `\input` to imports those directly into the parent document without having to remove/comment the preamble required to compile the `tikzpicture` by itself.

Comment: @puk: Have a look at the answer to this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31825/figure-preview-wrapper

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen yes I see the benefit now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. If you have a file `diagram.tex` with your TikZ instructions, just use the following

```
\begin{figure*}[tbp]
\input{diagram.tex}
\caption{This is my diagram.}
\label{f:diagram}
\end{figure*}
```

This should work just fine.

Comment: I was just about to flag this question as a duplicate, but then you answered. I was not aware that you could input it via an external file. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

In the preamble add     `\usepackage{tikz}` and necessary tikz libraries and in the document

```
    \begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering{
    \resizebox{0.8\textwidth}{!}{\input{diagram.tex}}}
    \caption{This is my diagram} \label{fig:diagram}
    \end{figure}
```

This enables to control the figure dimensions in your text.

Comment: can you describe what `\resizebox{0.8\textwidth}{!}` does

Comment: @puk You can adjust the size of the picture. Change `0.8\textwidth` to say `0.4\textwidth` and see your self.