# Referencing pgfplots figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

If i have a pgfplots figure in some place in my file, how can i reference it afterwards?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{loglogaxis}[legend pos=outer north east, xlabel={\#FLOPS}, ylabel={time in $s$}]
        \addplot coordinates {(10, 41069)(100, 36272)(1000, 37183)(10000, 49653)(100000, 173360)(1000000, 524701)(10000000, 10161288)(100000000, 87902501)(1000000000, 167910718)(10000000000, 20320627286)(100000000000, 217273232886)(1000000000000, 538049137671)};
        \addlegendentry{ Fastor2D};
        \addplot coordinates {(10, 39855)(100, 39227)(1000, 44272)(10000, 84625)(100000, 513951)(1000000, 3837277)(10000000, 65969067)(100000000, 425001508)(1000000000, 4048751612)(10000000000, 138821215507)(100000000000, 1389186505532)(1000000000000, 21198591175187)};
        \addlegendentry{ Blitz2D};
        \addplot coordinates {(10, 53834)(100, 113760)(1000, 59743)(10000, 182387)(100000, 226761)(1000000, 837170)(10000000, 1494975)(100000000, 8200807)(1000000000, 39245264)(10000000000, 277082078)(100000000000, 2545527258)(1000000000000, 24608770325)};
        \addlegendentry{ XTensor2D};
        \addplot coordinates {(10, 36895)(100, 44634)(1000, 39723)(10000, 48519)(100000, 52027)(1000000, 256271)(10000000, 1463178)(100000000, 11635263)(1000000000, 109152391)(10000000000, 708908499)(100000000000, 7235686838)(1000000000000, 69532828884)};
        \addlegendentry{ Eigen2D};
    \end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

If this is the figure, how can i say, e.g.: Like seen in figure 6 eigen compares nicely to fastor. ? And is it possible to collect all my figures in one file and then just reference them later on in my text? How would latex figure out where to put the figures?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) [What is the correct way to caption a `tikzpicture`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28258/134144) and [Outsourcing TikZ code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79594/134144)  might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `tikzpicture` is inside a figure with a caption, it can be referenced:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{loglogaxis}[legend pos=outer north east, xlabel={\#FLOPS}, ylabel={time in $s$}]
        \addplot coordinates {(10, 41069)(100, 36272)(1000, 37183)(10000, 49653)(100000, 173360)(1000000, 524701)(10000000, 10161288)(100000000, 87902501)(1000000000, 167910718)(10000000000, 20320627286)(100000000000, 217273232886)(1000000000000, 538049137671)};
        \addlegendentry{ Fastor2D};
        \addplot coordinates {(10, 39855)(100, 39227)(1000, 44272)(10000, 84625)(100000, 513951)(1000000, 3837277)(10000000, 65969067)(100000000, 425001508)(1000000000, 4048751612)(10000000000, 138821215507)(100000000000, 1389186505532)(1000000000000, 21198591175187)};
        \addlegendentry{ Blitz2D};
        \addplot coordinates {(10, 53834)(100, 113760)(1000, 59743)(10000, 182387)(100000, 226761)(1000000, 837170)(10000000, 1494975)(100000000, 8200807)(1000000000, 39245264)(10000000000, 277082078)(100000000000, 2545527258)(1000000000000, 24608770325)};
        \addlegendentry{ XTensor2D};
        \addplot coordinates {(10, 36895)(100, 44634)(1000, 39723)(10000, 48519)(100000, 52027)(1000000, 256271)(10000000, 1463178)(100000000, 11635263)(1000000000, 109152391)(10000000000, 708908499)(100000000000, 7235686838)(1000000000000, 69532828884)};
        \addlegendentry{ Eigen2D};
    \end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{text}
\label{eigen_vs_fastor}
\end{figure}

Like seen in figure \ref{eigen_vs_fastor} eigen compares nicely to fastor. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what i was looking for. I would like to upvote your post, but i don't have enough reputation